# Is there any work on updating the matrix inverse for matrices represented by a low rank approximation?

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrices in question are represented using $\sigma I + VV^T$ where $\sigma$ is a scalar, $I$ is the identity matrix and $V$ is of dimensions $n,s$ where $n$ denotes the length of a matrix and $s$ the approximation fidelity. I know that a low rank approximation means something different, but I do not know what the term for matrices in the above form is.

Also despite the question, I am interested in how they work in general.

Answer (score 2):

This is not intended as a direct answer to your first question, but could provide some insight applicable to your more general interest.  Let
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{Q}} }  = \sigma {\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } _{\left[ n \right]}} + \underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} } ^T} = \sigma \left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}} + \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)$$
where
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} }  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt \sigma  }}\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} }$$
It may (or may not) be well known that two consecutive uses of the generalized Woodbury identity yield
$$\begin{array}{c}
{\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}} + \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)^{ - 1}} = {\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } _{\left[ n \right]}} - \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } {\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ s \right]}} + {{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } } \right)^{ - 1}}{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } ^T}\\
 = {\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } _{\left[ n \right]}} - \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } ^T} + \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } {\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } ^T}{\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}} + \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)^{ - 1}}\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } ^T}
\end{array}$$
This may then be recursively expanded as many times as desired to obtain
$${\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}} + \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)^{ - 1}} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{2m - 1} {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^i}{{\left( {\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)}^i}}  + {\left( {\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } {{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)^m}{\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}} + \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)^{ - 1}}{\left( {\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)^m}$$
Thus, in the limit
$${\left( {{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ n \right]}} + \underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)^{ - 1}} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^i}{{\left( {\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } \,{{\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} } }^T}} \right)}^i}}$$
as long as the series actually converges, which requires the largest singular value of $\underline {\overline {\bf{X}} }$ to be less than 1, or, equivalently, the largest singular value of $\underline {\overline {\bf{V}} }$ to be less than  $\sqrt \sigma$.

Comment: I saw it this way of representing the matrix in a relative natural gradient draft paper. The intention of this is to do something similar to updating a whitening matrix which would require an inverse of a covariance matrix. For a full matrix I could use the Woodbury identity, but I am not sure what would be right with the approximate representation so I am probing for insight. I am looking for an alternative to implementing the log-det version of the cost function for approximating the inverse of a matrix which would be a huge pain to implement.

Comment: There was a version based on the L2 norm $||g'^{-1} g - I||$ which I could not get to work using stochastic gradient descent. I tried optimizing $g'^{-1}$ using the L2 cost when it was a full matrix, but the cost never improved much past the identity.